# Set file extension icon Cocoa

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I'm currently doing it this way but I have to save it twice before the icon shows on the file:

```
override func save(to url: URL, ofType typeName: String, for saveOperation: NSSaveOperationType, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        NSWorkspace.shared().setIcon(NSApp.applicationIconImage, forFile: url.path, options: NSWorkspaceIconCreationOptions(rawValue: 0))

        super.save(to: url, ofType: typeName, for: saveOperation, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
```

How can I set the icon for my file extension as soon as its being saved?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not 100% if I'm missing something else here, but we do this, and it **looks** like all you need to do is modify your `info.plist` with this row:

[image]

Unfortunately the dev that originally implemented this did so 8 years ago and is long gone, so I can't confirm if there are other steps you need to take.  Let me know if it doesn't work and I can dig around for you some more

EDIT: [Apple documentation on Document Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW9)